# Can we conclude $p_n < n^2$ from $\zeta(2)$ and Euler's prime theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{p_n}$$
diverges. And we know too that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{n^2}$$
converges (to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$). That means that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{p_n} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{n^2}.$$
My question is: Can we conclude from line 3 that $p_n <n^2$?

Comment: I'd say you have the inequality between those series exactly the opposite right way...

Comment: in general, you can deduce only that $p_n<n^2$ for infinitely many $n$; even better you can use the convergent series $\sum 1/(n\log^2 n)$

Comment: A general proof will be hard to come by since $p_1 > 1^2$.

Comment: But we also have $\sum \frac{1}{p_n} > \sum \frac{10^{10}}{n^2}$. So do we have that $p_n<10^{-10}n^2$ for all $n$?